# Why do i have this error in Scala Twilio on custom call create

Tags: html, scala, twilio, twilio-twiml

I try to develop a call with a custom text generated from my script in Scala.
I tried to convert into a custom string with xml tags but it still doesn t work.
However, if i add an link with xml file hosted, it works.

```scala
  val twimlString = say.toXml()
  println(twimlString)
  Call.creator(toPhoneNumber, fromPhoneNumber, twimlString).create()
```

[image: ApiException: Invalid application sid]